# How use vaadin-grid element selection as google drive selection?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component, vaadin-grid

There is my problem.

I'm trying to use the `<vaadin-grid>` element as a file explorer, and I have an issue with the selection.

This is what I want to reproduce :

- When I click just one line (anywhere on the row), the other line is/are unselected.
- If I click on the checkbox selection (or CTRL key) it will keep the preselected line and allow me to select multiple line.
- But at the time I click on another row (without CTRL and not on the checkbox), only this clicked line is selected.

(for the CTRL key I know it's out of context, just for the example :) ).

So, it's a mix of single and multi selection.
Currently,

- in 'multi' selection state, when I click on a row, this row is not selected and there is no event to tell that this row has been clicked, the only way is to click on the checkbox.
- In 'single' selection state, when I click on a row this row is selected but I can't do multiple selection.

Do you know how I can do that or what's the better approach ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is an example to respond to my request on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ugt4ffbr/). Thanks to Tomi Virkki and Jouni Koivuviita who answered to me.

To fix my issue the best is to use the new iteration of the vaadin-grid (v2.0).
This will allow me to get the selection I wanted (CTRL key was a bonus in my request) when I click on a row, the row is selected and to get a custom selection I use the checkbox.

To allow that this is the code that work :

```
<dom-module id="test-component">
<template>
  <iron-media-query query="(max-width: 350px)" query-matches="{{narrow}}"></iron-media-query>

  <vaadin-grid id="grid" items="[[users]]" on-active-item-changed="activeItemChanged" page-size="20" size="1000000">

    <vaadin-grid-selection-column frozen>
    </vaadin-grid-selection-column>

    <vaadin-grid-column>
      <template class="header">First</template>
      <template>[[item.name.first]]</template>
    </vaadin-grid-column>

    <vaadin-grid-column hidden="[[narrow]]">
      <template class="header">Last</template>
      <template>[[item.name.last]]</template>
    </vaadin-grid-column>

  </vaadin-grid>

</template>
<script>
  document.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
    Polymer({
      is: 'test-component',

      activeItemChanged: function(e) {
        var activeItem = e.detail.value;
        this.$.grid.selectedItems = [activeItem];
      },

      ready: function() {
        this.$.grid.dataProvider = function(params, callback) {
          var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
              callback(JSON.parse(this.responseText).results);
            }
          };
          xhttp.open("GET", "https://randomuser.me/api?results=20", true);
          xhttp.send();
        };
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

The `on-active-item-changed="activeItemChanged"` attribute that call this function, will select only the line 'active' when a cell is selected, and the `<vaadin-grid-selection-column frozen></vaadin-grid-selection-column>` Is used for the checkbox column.